# Stacking canvases and transparency

Tags: html5-canvas

Two canvases one on top of the other as below. The second canvas cvs should be transparent since by default all canvases are transparent and I do a clearRect just to make sure.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="430"></canvas>
    <canvas id="cvscan" style="display:none"></canvas>
    <script>
        var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var cvs = document.getElementById('cvscan');
        var cvsctx = cvs.getContext('2d');

        context.save();
        context.clearRect(0, 0, 578, 430);
        context.fillStyle = 'gray';
        context.fillRect(0, 0, 578, 430);

        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(0, 0);
        context.lineWidth = 3;
        context.lineTo(578, 430);
        context.strokeStyle = '#444444';
        context.stroke();

        context.moveTo(578, 0);
        context.lineTo(0, 430);
        context.stroke();

        cvs.width = 200;
        cvs.height = 200;
        cvsctx.clearRect(0, 0, cvscan.width, cvscan.height);
        var curimg = cvsctx.getImageData(0, 0, cvs.width, cvs.height);
        context.putImageData(curimg, 50, 50);

        context.restore();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I believe the second canvas should be transparent and (since there's nothing drawn in it) invisible -- but it's filled with white. What am I missing?

UPDATE this is what I see -- I believe the white box should not be there.

[Here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sl7f0.png)

Answer (score 1):

The *canvas with id="cvscan"* is being cleared, which means the image data is being set to 0 for all, **rgba(0,0,0,0)**, values.

Next, that image data is being painted onto the *canvas with id="myCanvas"*, updating the pixel on *"myCanvas"* to zero.

So, the canvas (*"myCanvas"*) is now transparent at the painted location, and is seen as *white*, because the background of the body is now showing.

To validate the results a test was run logging the data of the image, and then updating **bgcolor** to red.

(see photos)
[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but perhaps I didn't make my point. In the code I am copying the non-displayed canvas on top of the canvas with the lines. I believe after the putImageData I should not see the overlayed canvas because it's transparent -- but I do see it.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Was thinking it worked like photoshop layers.